# removing Spring Roo in gvNIX

Tags: spring-roo, gvnix

I tried to remove Spring Roo in project with gvNIX, using the following steps:

- Step 1: Push-In Refactor
- Step 2: Annotation Source Code Removal
- Step 3: Annotation JAR Removal

which are documented in:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/removing.html

But I have found that the removal is completed with some errors:

- The Java classes that using the utility "occ checksum" are with compilation errors (the method getMessageDigest(), its declare in .aj)
- All files .aj are not deleted (EquipoController_Roo_GvNIXDatatables.aj, ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean_Roo_GvNIXGeoConversionService.aj)

If I delete the files .aj and utility "occ checksum" is not used, everything is correct.

It is a bug in gvNIX? Maybe it could fix for the next version

> //Creating Petclinic project
>
> project --topLevelPackage com.gvnix.gmt --projectName gmt
>
> // Persistence
>
> jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_PERSISTENT
>
> // Creating entitys and fields
>
> entity jpa --class ~.domain.Equipo --sequenceName EQU_SEQ
>
> field string --fieldName nombre --notNull --sizeMin 3 --sizeMax 30 --class ~.domain.Equipo
>
> // Adding finders
>
> finder add --finderName findEquiposByNombre --class ~.domain.Equipo
>
> // Adding web layers
>
> web mvc setup
>
> web mvc all --package ~.web
>
> web mvc finder all
>
> web mvc language --code de
>
> web mvc language --code es
>
> // Enable gvNIX JPA utilities
>
> jpa gvnix setup
>
> // Creates a Spring @Service class with methods for entity batch updates
>
> jpa batch all
>
> // Enable gvNIX Web MVC Batch utilities
>
> web mvc batch setup
>
> // Add support for JPA batch operations in all controllers
>
> web mvc batch all
>
> // Adding JQuery, Datatables and Bootstrap
>
> web mvc jquery setup
>
> web mvc datatables setup
>
> web mvc jquery all
>
> web mvc bootstrap setup
>
> // Creating master patterns
>
> web mvc datatables add --type ~.web.EquipoController
>
> // Setup menu
>
> menu setup
>
> // Adding Optimistic Concurrency Control
>
> occ checksum set --entity ~.domain.Equipo
>
> logging setup --level INFO
>
> // Dynamic Configuration
>
> configuration create --name local
>
> configuration property add --name log4j.rootLogger
>
> configuration property value --configuration local --property
>
> log4j.rootLogger --value ERROR
>
> configuration list
>
> configuration export
>
> // Modifying persistence to use POSTRGRES database with geo spatial support
>
> jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database POSTGRES --userName gvnix --databaseName postgis_example --password gvnix --hostName localhost
>
> // Adding spatial support to our project
>
> jpa geo setup --provider HIBERNATE_SPATIAL
>
> // Adding new geo fields to Owner entity
>
> field geo --fieldName localizacion --type POINT --class ~.domain.Equipo
>
> // Generating geo entity finders
>
> finder geo all
>
> // Modifying entity field to use Geo component
>
> web mvc geo field --controller ~.web.EquipoController --field localizacion
>
> // Creating different map views
>
> web mvc geo controller --class ~.web.MapaEquipoController --preferredMapping mapequipos
>
> web mvc geo entity add --controller ~.web.EquipoController --map mapequipos
>
> web mvc geo controller --class ~.web.MapaGlobalController --preferredMapping mapaglobal
>
> web mvc geo entity add --controller ~.web.EquipoController --map mapaglobal
>
> //web mvc geo entity all
>
> // Generating all entities geo web layer
>
> // Adding base layers to our maps views
>
> web mvc geo tilelayer --name satellit --url "http://maptile.maps.svc.ovi.com/maptiler/maptile/newest/satellite.day/{z}/{x}/{y}/256/png8"
>
> web mvc geo wmslayer --name "geological map of valencia" --url "http://mapas.igme.es/gis/services/Cartografia_Geologica/IGME_GeologicoCValenciana_400/MapServer/WMSServer" --format "image/png" --transparent true --version "1.1.1" --crs EPSG4326 --layers "0,1,2,3"
>
> // Adding tools to our maps views
>
> web mvc geo tool measure --name measure
>
> web mvc geo tool custom --name latlng --icon fa-location-arrow --activateFunction activateLatLngTool --deactivateFunction deactivateLatLngTool --iconLibrary fa

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for. If you remove Spring Roo also must follow the same steps for all gvNIX artifact (annotations, *.aj files, etc). Take account that gvNIX are a collection of add-ons on the top of Spring Roo utilities.

Comment: Yes, I follow the same steps for all gvNIX artifact, but I found these errors.  Specifically, performing Step 1: Push-In Refactor it does not work well with feature "occ checksum" and some files ".aj" are not automatically deleted.

Comment: What is the content of reminder _.aj_? I'm not sure that is a gvNIX matter but could be of AJDT plugin instead. Try to make the push-in by hand.

Comment: The class Equipo.java uses feature "occ checksum", but to performing "Step 1: Push-In Refactor" in method "String checksumDigest()" are with compilation errors (the method getMessageDigest() in undefined), due to is declared in Equipo_Roo_gvNIX_occChecksum.
I can fix this by hand, but I thought it's something that ought to be automatically implemented by the add-on to remove Spring Roo.

Answer (score 0):

If you think it is possible bug, raise bug against gvNIX, reference this questions and give more details and how to reproduce bug.